# How will i get to use the darw2d and graphiti for drawing flowcharts?

Tags: javascript, raphael, draw2d

Here is the link : http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/

I want to create flowchart as in the above link using the draw2d library and now the prob is that it is not open source and it is paid, but i have some queries before buying this product:

-Want to confirm regarding licensing.

-Want to know support provided by them.

-Need to know if i can use trial version first before buying the product.

If any body know how to contact them please let me know, its very urgent.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Just checking...  Did you use the contact form on their site to send the URL of this questions?  http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/contact-form/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

License is dual: GPL and Commercial
Support: Yes - we provide support but we are limited in our manpower.
Trial: no. The software is between $4 and $10.

greetings

Comment: Hi Andreas Herz,

Thanks for the reply, I want to use graphiti i.e, there are two : Draw2D and Graphiti as mentioned here at http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/demos.html.
Kindly provide me details on how i can you Graphiti, Is that open source?
Or if it is not open source, Kindly provide me details for the same its licensing and pricing and how can I can i get to use.

Thanks and regards